# FtpWebRequest while writing to stream if network goes down then FTP Server gives access denied problem when tried to re upload

Tags: c#, ftpwebrequest

I am using FtpWebRequest to upload a file.
Facing a problem of which i am not getting solution.

While uploading a heavy file if network get disconnected then FTP server acquires lock on file being uploaded, now when user tries to re upload the same file then it get access denied error.

I have set TimeOut and ReadWriteTimeOut to 5 secs of FtpWebRequest on FTP Server it is 10 secs.
Even if i try to upload same file after an Hour then also same problem exist.

```
 // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
  request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://" + FtpInfo.FtpServer.Trim() + "/" + FtpInfo.FtpFolderPath.Trim() + "/" + FileName.Trim()));
   request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
   request.Proxy = null;

   // FTP site uses anonymous logon.
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(FtpInfo.UserNameForFTP.Trim(), FtpInfo.PasswordForFTP.Trim());
    request.UsePassive = FtpInfo.UsePassive;
    request.KeepAlive = FtpInfo.KeepAlive;
    request.Timeout = FtpInfo.TimeOut; //Milliseconds
    request.UseBinary = true;
    request.ReadWriteTimeout = FtpInfo.TimeOut; //Milliseconds

                        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(SourceLocation);
                        long length = fi.Length;
                        BytesUploaded = length;

                        long uploadSize = 0;
                        if (chunks == 0)
                        {
                            chunks = 1024;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            buffLength = chunks;
                        }
                        byte[] buff = new byte[buffLength];
                        int contentLen;
                        using (FileStream fs = fi.OpenRead())
                        {
                            using (Stream strm = request.GetRequestStream())
                            {
                                contentLen = fs.Read(buff, 0, buffLength);
                                try
                                {
                                    while (contentLen != 0)
                                    {
                                        Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)delegate() { lblProgress.Content = "Uploading '" + FileName + "'......" + "Bytes Uploaded (" + uploadSize.ToString() + "/" + length.ToString() + ")"; });
                                        strm.Write(buff, 0, contentLen);
                                        uploadSize += contentLen;
                                        contentLen = fs.Read(buff, 0, buffLength);
                                    }
                                    strm.Close();
                                }
                                catch (Exception ex)
                                {
                                    if (strm!=null)
                                    {
                                        try
                                        {
                                            strm.Close();
                                        }
                                        catch
                                        {
                                            throw ex;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    throw ex;
                                }
                            }
                            fs.Close();
                        }


                        try
                        {
                            //requestStream.Close(); -orignal
                            fi = null;
                            request=null;
                        }
                        catch { }
```

Comment: Please post your file access code.

Comment: is the "access denied" a local message OR is it an error that the server sends ?

Comment: @Yahia {"Unable to write data to the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine."}

Comment: are you reusing the request object ?

Comment: @Yahia No above code is written on a button click every time new object being created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was problem related to the FTP Server we were using, when we switched FTP server to IIS then everything worked smoothly.
Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 1):

I don't know enough about your app (is the FTP upload on a separate thread for example) but try this:

```
bool DoneOK = false;
FtpWebRequest request = null;
FtpWebResponse response = null;
try {
    // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
    FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://" + FtpInfo.FtpServer.Trim() + "/" + FtpInfo.FtpFolderPath.Trim() + "/" + FileName.Trim()));
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
    request.Proxy = null;

    // FTP site uses anonymous logon.
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(FtpInfo.UserNameForFTP.Trim(), FtpInfo.PasswordForFTP.Trim());
    request.UsePassive = FtpInfo.UsePassive;
    request.KeepAlive = FtpInfo.KeepAlive;
    request.Timeout = FtpInfo.TimeOut; //Milliseconds
    request.UseBinary = true;
    request.ReadWriteTimeout = FtpInfo.TimeOut; //Milliseconds

    long length = new FileInfo(SourceLocation).Length;
    long uploadSize = 0;
    if ( chunks < 1 )
         chunks = 1024;

    buffLength = chunks;
    byte[] buff = new byte[buffLength];
    int contentLen = 0;
    string MSG = "";

    using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead (SourceLocation))
    using (Stream strm = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        while ((contentLen = fs.Read(buff, 0, buffLength)) > 0 )
        {
        MSG = "Uploading '" + FileName + "'......" + "Bytes Uploaded (" + uploadSize.ToString() + "/" + length.ToString() + ")";
        string tmp_MSG = MSG;
        Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, () => { lblProgress.Content = tmpMSG; });
        strm.Write(buff, 0, contentLen);
        uploadSize += contentLen;
        };

        strm.Close();

        // necessary - the upload occurs really here !
        response = (FtpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
        // check the response codes... for example FileActionOK...
        if ( response.StatusCode == System.Net.FtpStatusCode.FileActionOK )
             DoneOK = true;

        response.Close(); response = null;
        request = null;
    }
    }
catch
{
};

if ( request != null )    
     {
     if ( response != null )
          {
          try { response.Close(); } catch {};
          response = null;
          }

     if ( !DoneOK )
          {
          try { request.Abort (); } catch {};
          }

     request = null;
     }
```

Comment: problem is that what if network gets disconnected on client machine while writting stream, in this case an exception will be thrown but there will be no way to communicate Ftp Server to close the stream because there is no network, now Ftp Server will never know that connection has gone down, it will wait that stream is getting written, now client will again try to upload file when network problem resolves and when it tries to upload Ftp Server will return error because file is in use as stream is still open.

Comment: that is not how FTP works... please try the code... you can easily simulate "network down" by removing the cable for 30 seconds or so, then see what happens when you try to upload again

Comment: I tried same i put a breakpoint on code line strm.Write(buff, 0, contentLen);

Comment: Sorry!! I tried same i put a breakpoint on code line strm.Write(buff, 0, contentLen); and plug out the cable then it throws exception and still i have not plugged the cable, so stream remains open secondly even Abort would not help because it will not be able to send this command to Server.

Comment: I really don't understand what you are testing... the breakpoint has nothing to do with test... it can change the result of the test!