# Is FtpWebRequest class Serializable ?

Tags: c#, serialization

I want to serialize an instance of FtpWebRequest class. Is it possible? When i tried, it gave me error that class is not marked serializable which means I cannot serialize the object but in msdn documentation they mention explicit implementation of ISerializable.GetObjectData

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest_members(v=vs.90).aspx

What does it mean? Can I serialize it or not? confused pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it isn't. While it inherits `ISerializable`, it lacks the necessary serialization constructor. But perhaps a better question would be:

> In what context could it possible *make sense* to serialize this?

and I can't think of one. A *request* is an *operational* class; it is better to serialize *data* (the *state* of your system) - not the spinning cogs that make it work. For the same reasons, I wouldn't attempt to serialize a connection, a file-stream, etc.

Figure out what *data* you need to know to get your system back into the necessary state; serialize the data.

Comment: I am facing a strange problem, due to which i was thinking if possible i could serialize FtpWebRequest. Scenario is :-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144180/ftpwebrequest-while-writing-to-stream-if-network-goes-down-then-ftp-server-gives

Comment: @Deepesh I don't personally see serialization as a solution to that

Comment: what i was thinking is when i am uploading a file and gets the error of network disconnection i serialize the object and when next time user try to upload a file, i deserialize the object and close the last opened stream due to which i am getting access denied error.

Answer (score 1):

It's not, and the method is explained thusly:

*Infrastructure. When overridden in a descendant class, populates a SerializationInfo instance with the data needed to serialize the WebRequest. (Inherited from WebRequest.)*

That means it's an infrastructure method (used by .NET code internally).  The `WebRequest` class is serialisable, and it needs data to be serialised either from this class directly or perhaps a base class of `FtpWebRequest`.

Following the link even says:

*This API supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code.*

Comment: To be fair, `GetObjectData` and the matching constructor are *never* intended to be used directly from your code.... (that by itself isn't directly tied to whether it is serializable)

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of it the FtpWebrequest class allow you to interact with a server but the method GetObjectData requires that the object that is being retrieved must be serializable for obvious reasons.  Have a look at this question to see how it is implemented:

[Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222517/deserialization-doesnt-work-though-i-implement-getobjectdata-method-and-construc/1222671#1222671)